# Project file expected at

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have this line in my code

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

and this part of it

```
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

gets highlighted by Visual Studio with the error

> Project file expected at `<path>`.

What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Is the file included in your project, and in that particular location?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using ReSharper? If so, it may be due to this issue:
http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/287081

In summary, make sure the jquery file is actually included in the project by right clicking it in solution explorer and selecting 'Include in project'.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what Ian Newson said you can also directly edit the .proj file. Make sure you have a line like

```
<Content Include="My\Custom\Path\My.ascx" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Source="pack://application:,,,/path/file.svg"` and in my case something was apparently messed up in my project, so I had to clear ReSharper's cache and restart Visual Studio, and when Visual Studio came back the resource files were not included in the project anymore, so I had to re-include them, and mark them all as "Resource" and "Do not copy". Once I did that, the warnings disappeared.